# vscode plugin REST Client

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

```
###
@id = 5ead67de63c073fdd86ccff5
POST   http://localhost:3000/products/{{id}}
Content-Type: application/json

[
   {
       "propName": "name",
        "value": "CampbellTomatoJuice"
   } 
]
```

When I use postman for the above no issues, but vscode plugin REST Client throws out an error HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: I am using this plugin with typescript and I have noticed if I target es5 everything works great but if I target es2015 I only get 404's. I have not clue how to solve it though. The only answer does not solve my issue.

Comment: have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the protocol (`HTTP/1.1`):

```
@id = 5ead67de63c073fdd86ccff5
POST   http://localhost:3000/products/{{id}} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

[
   {
       "propName": "name",
        "value": "CampbellTomatoJuice"
   } 
]
```